# Is there anyway to autoplay online content audio file on ipad

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, ipod

I want to play audio file on ipad which is located on some server. but thing is I want to autoplay audio file using HTML5. Please suggest me the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoplay attribute is [purposely disabled on iPhone and iPad](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1):

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices,
>   including iPad), where the user may be
>   on a cellular network and be charged
>   per data unit, preload and autoplay
>   are disabled. No data is loaded until
>   the user initiates it. This means the
>   JavaScript play() and load() methods
>   are also inactive until the user
>   initiates playback, unless the play()
>   or load() method is triggered by user
>   action. In other words, a
>   user-initiated Play button works, but
>   an onLoad="play()" event does not.

Having said that there are some hacks for [iOS 3](http://roblaplaca.com/blog/2010/04/14/ipad-and-iphone-html5-video-autoplay/) and [iOS 4](http://www.codeblog.co/getting-autoplay-working-on-ios/) to work around this with JavaScript.  On iOS 3 you can create a link element and then simulate a click event to trigger the media element to play; on iOS4 you can simply call the `load()` and `play()` methods directly on the element.

Comment: Thanks robertc..can you please give me example of calling load and play method directly on the element

Comment: @TusharAhirrao Your tried which one, the iOS 3 work around or the iOS 4 one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com/play.mp3"] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 10];

        [myWebView loadRequest: request];       
        [request release];
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks Anish. But I am using HTML5.

Comment: but where should i put this code in my html file?...In <script> tag or body tag ....please tell me the location

Comment: You are loading server html content.So why should you use your html file.

Comment: There is no way to play audio file autoplay on ipad.. i had also facing same issue thing is ipad required physical touch to play any audio file